# PHP: Removing only the first few empty <p> tags

Tags: php, regex, content-management-system

I have a custom developed CMS where users can enter some content into a rich text field (ckeditor).

Users simply copy-paste data from another document. Sometimes the data has empty `<p>` tags at the beginning. Here's a sample of the data:

```
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p>Data data data data</p>
<p>Data data data data</p>
<p>Data data data data</p>
<p>Data data data data</p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p>Data data data data</p>
<p>Data data data data</p>
<p></p>
```

I don't want to remove all the empty `<p>` tags, only the ones before the actual data, the top 3 `<p>` tags in this case.

How can I do that?

Edit: To clarify, I need a PHP solution. Javascript won't do.

Is there a way I can gather all `<p>` tags in an array, then iterate and delete until I encounter one with data?

Comment: While I gave a regexp solution, if you want to parse HTML, and iterate over elements, see http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ (or `DOMDocument::loadHTML`, although it's a bit heavy for a task like this).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, don't use regular expressions for irregular strings: it [stirs the sleeping god](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Instead, use XPath:

```
function strip_opening_lines($html) {  
  $dom = new DOMDocument();
  $dom->preserveWhitespace = FALSE;
  $dom->loadHTML($html);

  $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
  $nodes = $xpath->query("//p");

  foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    // Remove non-significant whitespace.
    $trimmed_value = trim($node->nodeValue);

    // Check to see if the node is empty (i.e. <p></p>). 
    // If so, remove it from the stack.
    if (empty($trimmed_value)) {
      $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
    }
    // If we found a non-empty node, we're done. Break out.
    else {
      break;
    }
  }
  $parsed_html = $dom->saveHTML();

  // DOMDocument::saveHTML adds a DOCTYPE, <html>, and <body> 
  // tags to the parsed HTML. Since this is regular data, 
  // we can use regular expressions.
  preg_match('#<body>(.*?)<\/body>#is', $parsed_html, $matches);

  return $matches[1];
}
```

Reasons why all the regex solutions presented are bad:

- Won't match empty paragraph elements with attributes (e.g. `<p class="foo"></p>`)
- Won't match empty paragraph elements that are not literally empty (e.g. `<p> </p>`)

Comment: Good idea, but I tried your code. And it doesn't remove any tags, instead, it prepending `&Acirc;`(`Â`) characters within the `<p>` tags. Weird!

Comment: And it's not the regex that's causing it.

Comment: Also, I'm getting a tonne of warnings. They're either `expecting ';' in Entity` or `No name in Entity`

Comment: @gAMBOOKa what version of PHP? What is seed string you are using?

Comment: 5.3.1 - `<p>

 ;&nbsp;</p>

<p>

 The results show that the next two years will see a more intense focus on growth, with respondents reporting that markets are more varied and volatile than before the crisis. Margins are under pressure, with almost 50% reporting price erosion and almost 30% reporting increases in costs for labor and key inputs.</p>

<p>

 &nbsp;</p>` - It's quite a large string, an entire article

Comment: @gAMBOOKa `&nbsp;` is a non-breaking space, which by definition means the elements aren't empty. The first element in your test data has a semi colon; again, not an empty paragraph element. You can use [`trim()`](http://php.net/trim) or [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace) to remove any characters that shouldn't count. I have updated my answer to remove all non-signficant whitespace, though.

Comment: Thank you for the link to the sleeping god. Best comment i've ever read on StackOverflow

Answer (score 3):

Normally I would advise against using a regular expression to parse HTML, but this one seems harmless:

```
$html = preg_replace('!^(<p></p>\s*)+!', '', $html);
```

Comment: `preg_replace( "!^(<p></p>\s*)+!", "", "<p></p><p>data</p>" )`- does not work - same output as input.

Comment: That returns `<p>data</p>` for me. (PHP 5.3.3)

Comment: You're right, my bad... it had a `<br>` inside the `<p>` for some reason

Comment: What happens if the first paragraph block is `<p class="regex-droolz"></p>`?

Comment: @gAMBOOKa how about when the element isn't *literally* empty? (e.g. `<p> </p>`, note the non-significant whitespace)

Comment: That's the issue I'm having right now. `(?:/>|>(?:\s|&nbsp;)` ain't working either.

Comment: @gAMBOOKa, all of that would have been good to know. ;) I wouldn't even have posted this answer had I known the data was variable like this. All of these things mentioned are why regexps are generally a bad way to modify HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$html = preg_replace ("~^(<p><\/p>[\s\n]*)*~iUmx", "", $html);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do it in javascript, as soon as performs paste operation, strip off unwanted tags using regular expressions,

your code will be like,

```
document.getElementById("id of rich text field").onkeyup = stripData; 
document.getElementById("id of rich text field").onmouseup = stripData; 

function stripData(){
    document.getElementById("id of rich text field").value = document.getElementById("id of rich text field").value.replace(/\<p\>\<\/p\>/g,"");
}
```

Edit: To remove initial empty

only,

```
 function stripData(){
        var dataStr = document.getElementById("id of rich text field").value 
        while(dataStr.match(/^\<p\>\<\/p\>/g)) {
           dataStr  = dataStr .replace(/^\<p\>\<\/p\>/g,"");
        }
        document.getElementById("id of rich text field").value = dataStr;
 }
```

Comment: That's not ideal. If javascript is disabled, the values won't be stripped and the user won't know why.

Comment: Then you can do it in PHP as well using http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php with same regular expression.

Comment: This seems like it will replace all empty `<p>` tags. That's not what I want to do.

Comment: actually in both cases thats going to hit all the empty `<p />` tags... not just the first three.

Comment: I've updated javascript version, you can convert javascript to appropriate PHP syntax using http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php & http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: @gAMBOOKA: sorry didnt catch the g modifier... in php i believe you need to use `m` instead for multiline. Check Chinmayee's link to the manual for more details.